# Getting results from each iteration of a thread, that runs an infinite loop

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a thread that loops while(true).  I don't want to exit this thread and relaunch it.  Instead, I want to control its iterations and get results from its work, every iteration.
So, basically, I want the controlling process to wait for the thread to return the results of some work, without exiting this thread.   I am using `ManualResetEvent`to `Set()` and `Reset()` the thread, which works, but I am not getting any returns

Comment: It sounds to me like you should be using Task.Run() for your method calls with a continuation token that then relaunches another task (or that same task).

Comment: I cannot use task run because I have to run this in a STAThread

Comment: you can use `Queue` and put results there. And in other thread grab the results from this queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you need to use some sorf of producer / consumer pattern using [BlockingCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx), it is designed to make this easy.